# HTML Table Styling

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

I'm encountering a problem when styling an dynamic generated table. The user can choose how many columns there have to be, some of them have got a fixed length. How can I let the other give a percentage of the space left, without having to specify the exact width of the columns every time AND without ending up with different column widths with different data/different browsers?

Example:

```
<style type="text/css">
table{
    width:800px;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
   /* table-layout: fixed; */
}

table td {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    border:1px solid #EEEEEE;
}

table tbody td.active{
    text-align:center;
    width:100px; /* fixed */
}

table tbody td.option{
    width:100px; /* fixed */
}


table tbody td.nonfixed{
    width:auto;
}
</style>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Active</td>
            <td colspan="2">Options</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5"><a href="">+ Add new row</a><td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="nonfixed">[Name 1]</td>
            <td class="nonfixed">[Description 1]</td>
            <td class="active">[X]</td>
            <td class="option">Edit</td>
            <td class="option">Delete</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="nonfixed">[Name 2]</td>
            <td class="nonfixed">[Description 2]</td>
            <td class="active">[0]</td>
            <td class="option">Edit</td>
            <td class="option">Delete</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the example both "nonfixed" columns should have the exact same width. This should also work when the user adds a nonfixed column or switches the first column with the last etc.

Who's able to help me out?

Comment: It's a near-certainty you're going to need JavaScript to pull this off. What have you tried in that area?

Comment: The following question came up when solving this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444436/html-table-thead-width-depending-on-tbody-in-chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possible approaches... either use a script to calculate the flexible-width columns' widths and average them, or use nested tables to split the two flex cols at 50%:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="fixed"></td>
    <td class="fixed"></td>
    <td class="fixed"></td>

    <td class="flex-wrapper">
      <table width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td width="50%"></td>
          <td width="50%"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: When I apply "table td.nonfixed{
        width:100%;
    }" this works for the elements. The only problem is that Chrome does require the thead elements to have width.

Comment: On the parent table? Can you use width: auto;?